# unable to fetch user data of comment in a post's view in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5, one-to-many

I have three models and corresponding tables. User,Post,Comment.
Column of users table are id, name, email.
Column of posts table are id, title, body.
Column of comments table are id, user_id, post_id, comment.

User model has this function as below:

```
public function comments(){

        return $this->hasMany('App\Comment');
    }
```

Post model has this function as below:

```
public function comments(){

        return $this->hasMany('App\Comment');
    }
```

Comment model has these two functions as below:

```
 public function user(){

        $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

    public function post(){

        $this->belongsTo('App\Post');
    }
```

single post showing function in PostController is as below:

```
public function show($slug)
    {
        $post = Post::where('slug', $slug)->first();
        return view('post.show')->withPost($post);
    }
```

and in show.blade.php i'm trying to achieve this functionality:

```
@foreach($post->comments as $comment)
<p>
{{$comment->user->name}}
 </p>
@endforeach
```

Why is it throwing error saying relationship method must return an object ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `return` the relationship, so your code becomes:

```
public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}

public function post(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Post');
}
```

Comment: Haha, happens to all of us :)